# Chrome extension to notify on StackExchange activity (and others)

Tags: chrome, notification

I am looking for a Chrome Extension to show a notification using Chrome's desktop notification center whenever (for example):

- I get a new email via Gmail
- I get a message/answer on StackExchange websites
- I get a message on Facebook
- Tweets

and possibly even more!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Chime](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chime/lkdfkbkkfdhhfnhgbphecddnpfnoedke/).

It's perfect! I found it recently while browsing through the Chrome Store (because that's just what I do ;p)

Services:

- Gmail
- reddit
- facebook
- twitter
- quora
- github
- flickr
- stack exchange
- foursquare
- google plus

You can just click the icon next to the address bar and any outstanding notification will be shown. You can mark them as read and then they disappear. There is a do not disturb mode where you won't be notified of anything.

Note 1: The extension says 'stackoverflow', but it shows all the notification from all the stackexchange sites.

Note 2: The Facebook private messages haven't been coming to me, some other person in the reviews said he had this problem as well (I don't know why).

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work anymore. Know any others?

Comment: @SarahofGaia hmmm it isn't! ;( not really - sorry! I'll unaccept this answer tho!

Comment: It's okay. This answer was given all the way back in 2014, so not a huge deal. Comes with the territory. :P

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for the Stack-Exchange-verse, there is [StackEye](https://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites).

I discovered it, much like you when I stumbled upon [stackapps](https://stackapps.com)